# Is checking LEN and ISNULL useful in addition to ISDATE?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking through a stored procedure and seeing many lines like:

```
case when len(isnull(INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE,'')) > 0 
      and isdate(INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE) = 1 
    then convert(datetime,INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE)
    else null end
```

and

```
case when len(isnull(SHIPMENT.NET_AMOUNT_DUE,'')) > 0 
      and isnumeric(SHIPMENT.NET_AMOUNT_DUE) = 1
   then convert(money,SHIPMENT.NET_AMOUNT_DUE) 
   else null end
```

I don't understand why the `ISNULL` and `LEN` checks are always there. Is there some benefit that I am missing? Conversely, is there any detriment to how the code is currently written?

Comment: The bigger question you should be asking is, "Why is INVOICE_DATE not a date/time type?"

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm still delving deeper into the whole process, but essentially this is part of a large import, with data coming in from XML. It looks that previously it's pulled straight in as `varchar` and then at this point gets checked for type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LEN` and `ISNULL` checks are not needed.

`ISDATE` and `ISNUMERIC` will return a `0` if the value is `NULL` or empty, so this is just not needed. Possibly someone being extra extra cautious...

These can be written as:

```
case when ISDATE(INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE) = 1 
    then convert(datetime,INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE)
    else null end
```

And:

```
case when ISNUMERIC(SHIPMENT.NET_AMOUNT_DUE) = 1
   then convert(money,SHIPMENT.NET_AMOUNT_DUE) 
   else null end
```